# Structure firestore query for saving document and collection at the same time

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I would like to save a list of products for each user and use geofirestore to find the product lists of the closest users.

But I mix my brushes with Firestore queries.

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import * as geofirestore from 'geofirestore';
```

```
const firestoreApp = firestore();
const GeoFirestore = geofirestore.initializeApp(firestoreApp);
const geocollection = GeoFirestore.collection('PRODUCTS');
```

```
geocollection
     .doc(user.uid)
        .set({
          coordinates: new firestore.GeoPoint(
            productLocation.lat,
            productLocation.long,
          ),
        })
          .collection('USER_PRODUCTS')
            .add({
              name: productName,
              description: productDescription,
              price: productPrice,
              quantity: productQuantity,
              image: productImage.name,
              createdDate: new Date(),
          });
```

I can only set the first doc with the user id and the coordinates, but cannot add the 'USER_PRODUCTS' collection.

Does it is possible to chain like that or I'll have to make two differents queries?

Someone have a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to make two different requests (one with Geofirestore and one with Firestore).
I guess and hope that there is a solution with only one query, but for the moment this solution works.

```
await geocollection.doc(user.uid).set({
        coordinates: new firestore.GeoPoint(
          productLocation.lat,
          productLocation.long,
        ),
      });

await firestore()
  .collection('PRODUCTS')
  .doc(user.uid)
  .collection('USER_PRODUCTS')
  .doc()
  .set(
    {
      name: productName,
      description: productDescription,
      price: productPrice,
      quantity: productQuantity,
      image: productImage.name,
      createdDate: new Date(),
    },
    {merge: true},
  );
```